# use canvas getImageData and my canvas background is empty

Tags: javascript, canvas

i use two canvas, one canvas load image, another one load imgage. when i use getImageData this function the first canvas's image is empty.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Canvas</title>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="1280" height="720" style="display: none;"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2')
    const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d')
    function init() {
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = './img/1.jpeg'
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
      }

      function draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0, 1280, 720)
        setTimeout(draw, 30)
      }
      setTimeout(draw, 30)
    }

    function init2() {
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = './img/1.jpg'
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, 720)
      }
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1)
      const img = new Image()
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL()
      img.style.display = 'none'
      document.body.appendChild(img)
      // console.log(imageData)
    }, 2000)

    init()
    init2()
  </script>
</html>
```

why use getImageData function can make the canvas background empty

Comment: You never close the `head` tag in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but is not the main issue